# Sequelize Update with Object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a code using sequelize to update one record and then return this updated record:

```
const companyId = req.params.id
const companyNewDetail = req.body
console.log("companyNewDetail", companyNewDetail)
await Company.update(companyNewDetail, {
    where: {
        companyId,
    },
})
const company = await Company.findOne({
    where: {
        companyId,
    },
})
res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: company })
```

It is working but I have to seperate into two query statements. Is there a way I can mix them together? I want to pass the update parameter with a object rather than destructuring the object and assign to the instance one by one.

Comment: you mean batch update or getting result back after update?

Comment: same as what I did: pass one object as a parameter for update and then send back the updated result back. I did this by two statements, is there a way only one statement?

Comment: no. when you update most sql dbs will only return provide only number of affected rows. Even if sequelize provide an interface through it, the implementation will not be difference than what you did logically

Answer (score 1):

The `returning` option of [Model.update](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update) still only supports PostgreSQL for `sequelize` v6.

For example:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

// const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

class Company extends Model {}
Company.init(
  {
    companyId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'companies' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Company.create({ name: 'google' });
    // test
    const companyId = 1;
    const companyNewDetail = { name: 'reddit' };
    const result = await Company.update(companyNewDetail, {
      where: {
        companyId,
      },
      returning: true,
    });
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

If you use `postgres` dialect, you will get the following result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "companies" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "companies" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "companies" ("companyId"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("companyId"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'companies' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "companies" ("companyId","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): UPDATE "companies" SET "name"=$1 WHERE "companyId" = $2 RETURNING *
[
  1,
  [
    Company {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: {},
      _modelOptions: [Object],
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    }
  ]
]
```

The first element of the `result` array is the number of affected rows for the updating operation. The second element is the sequelize model instances of updated rows.

For `sqlite3`, you will get:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (`companyId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`companies`)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `companies` (`companyId`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3);
Executing (default): UPDATE `companies` SET `name`=$1,`updatedAt`=$2 WHERE `companyId` = $3
[ undefined, 1 ]
```

So, you need to do an additional query for other databases after updating the rows in the table.